# How to chown a directory on a mounted samba share?

Tags: linux, access-control-list, user-permissions, samba4, chown

I have a linux client mounting a samba share with the following fstab entry:

```
//<serverip>/<nameofshare> /home/user -o nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=15s,vers=3.11,user=<sambauser>,uid=<clientuser>,gid=<clientuserprimarygroup>,cifsacl,credentials=/path/to/cred 0 0
```

On this mounted share I want to create a directory `foo` and chown so it belongs to user:group `bar`:`bar`. The problem is that, even as root, if I try chowning a file or directory like `chown -v bar:bar <file-or-directory>` I get the following error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '<file-or-directory>': Invalid argument
failed to change ownership of '<file-or-directory>' from user:<numeric gid> to bar:bar
```

In case it matters for some reason it seems like it is ignoring the gid in the mount command and previously created and new files show the same gid as the samba user. This didn't happen until recently and I'm not sure what changed. Here is the full mount command shown by `mount/mtab`:

```
//<serverip>/<sambashare> /home/user cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=<sambauser>,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=1000,noforcegid,addr=<serverip>,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,cifsacl,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1 0 0
```

I am not sure what is causing noforceuid to be put into the command. If I mount with forceuid and forcegid after uid and gid respectively forceuid replaces noforceuid, but old and new files still show the sambauser gid.

Samba server version is 4.19.5.

Comment: probably a user map problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the share to a certain path and then chown

```
mount smbshare /mnt
chown -r /mnt
```

Or mount it using the fstab then you  can add more options

Comment: As said in the question I did mount the the samba share to a certain path with fstab. -r isn't a real chown switch. chown -R produces the same error.